# POST request in restler php

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest, post

I'm a new user at REST architecture, now I'm trying to make a test with my API.
I like to call this method in the url but I don't know the right format.

My concern is that I have two parameters to be sent by post request.

```
public function CreateExemple ($name, $libelle)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is always be a good practice to use a ready to use package if available. There are lots of RESTful APIs available to use. It looks like you are using PHP for development. you can start with :

[Zend REST](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.html)